# Получить дату и время онлайн

Tags: javascript

Есть счетчик привязанный к дате, который считает (как бы) число умерших от курения. И работает по алгоритму +123 каждую секунду начиная с нуля. Этот счетчик нужно разместить на странице, к дате его привязали чтобы он не сбрасывался при обновлении страницы и для всех пользователей показывали одно и тоже число. Но проблема привязки к дате относительно даты пользователя является не очень хорошей практикой, т.к. они могут поменять дату на пк и увидеть уже неправильные числа или банально неправильная дата на пк так же приводит к фиаско. Поэтому было решение привязать счетчик к дате онлайн, однока как получить его онлайн не ясно. Из этого и вопрос, **Как получить дату онлайн в javascript?**

*счетчик привязанный к дате пользователя*

```js
  var startValue = 0;  
  var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();  
  var inSec = 123;  

  value = startValue + Math.round(((new Date).getTime() - startTime) / 1000 * inSec);
  
  function add() {
      value += inSec;
       document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = value;
  }
  
  setInterval(add, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="count">
</div>
```

[**Код на jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zrd5g1t7/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете получить текущее время либо через API, либо дополнительные скрипты.
Пример:

```js
    time100.init({
        timenow:{zone:"Europe/Moscow",format:"%H:%i:%s"}
    });
```

```html
<span class="timenow" id="time"></span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://time100.ru/t.js"></script>
```

Дополнения в код автора.

```js
    time100.init({
        timenow:{zone:"Europe/Moscow",format:"%Y,%m,%d %H:%i:%s"}
    });

    window.onload = function () {
        var time = document.getElementById('time').innerText;
        var startValue = 0;

        var startTime = (new Date(time)).getTime();
        
        var inSec = 123;

        value = startValue + Math.round(((new Date(time)).getTime() - startTime) / 1000 * inSec);

        function add() {
            value += inSec;
            document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = value;
        }
        setInterval(add, 1000);
    };
```

```html
<span class="timenow" id="time" hidden></span>
<div>Погибших от курения</div>
<div id="count"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://time100.ru/t.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, можете дополнить свой ответ, сделав счётчик с получаемой таким образом датой

Comment: @MidNightElf Добавил.

Comment: почему при обновлении страницы отсчет начинается заново?

Comment: прошу, сделайте последнее дополнение, так чтобы счетчик не сбрасывался при обновлении сайта, т.е. было одно и тоже число для всех пользователей посетивших сайт. Я много искал, такого ответа еще нету. Ваш ответ еще многим поможет

Comment: @MidNightElf Укажите просто фиксированное время начала отсчёта в `startTime`

Comment: Счетчик работает, только отсчет начинается с числа 1580995374

Comment: @MidNightElf во-первых это `timestamp`(Текущее время) так как есть параметр `startTime`! Если хотите, чтобы у всех было одинаковое число - Вам надо вести отчёт от определённой даты. По-этому Вам надо в параметр `startTime` Ввести СВОЮ дату и время в ввиде `timestamp`. О чём я и написал Вам в предыдущем комментарии.

Comment: @MidNightElf Почему отменили данное решение как правильное? Всё работает в соответствии с Вашими требованиями.

Comment: ой, случайно, не заметил, я ответ смотрел, случайно тапнул

Comment: @MidNightElf Ничего страншного Бывает ) Просто стало интересно.  Всё получилось у Вас сделать?

Comment: да, огромное спасибо

Comment: @MidNightElf Да не за что ) Главное что у Вас получилось решить задачу )))

Comment: ага, сделать счётчик наращивающий значения и показывающий его одинаково для всех пользователей и без нужды в хранении переменной в бд на сервере. Вышло замечательно